# Получение информации из других сайтов на своем сайте

Tags: javascript, xss

Я хочу сделать для сайта свою форму для перевода английских предложений, переводить их с помощью GoogleTranslate и возвращать обратно на свой сайт. Я слышал про межсайтовый скриптинг, но все же вопрос стоит, как это можно сделать на этом примере?

Comment: С гуглом можно. Но только на локальном хосте или на боевом сервере. Надо ключ доступа к API иметь и его использовать только на приписанных хостах

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api вот попробуйте. Если Вы слишком новы для NodeJS - то сейчас напишу другой пример

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, запрос по ссылке `https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key={apiKey}&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=hello` не прошел из-за следующей ошибки:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
            "message": "This API requires billing to be enabled on the project. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/billing?project=567816477920 to enable billing.",
            "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/billing?project=567816477920"
        }
    ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "This API requires billing to be enabled on the project. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/billing?project=567816477920 to enable billing."
    }
}
```

Для подключения и использования даного API, Вам ужно подтвердить кредитную карту(т.е возможность проведения платежей). Но в таком случае, у Вас лимиты выростут в разы. Если у Вас запросов больше чем на 150к в день - то нужно подключать дополнительные пакеты услуг.